# Why is there no cheer from people to Bhallaladeva when compared to Baahubali?

Tags: analysis, baahubali-the-beginning

In *Baahubali: The Beginning*, while preparing for the war against Kalakeya army, the adviser/priest(don't know what his job is exactly he is seen assisting Bijjaladeva and Bhallaladeva in the movie) calls Bhallaladeva to offer his obeisances to the war Goddess. At that time, not even one cheers or shouts but his loyal group soldiers bow to him. He then beheads a bull and gives a war cry, then his loyal group of soldiers and handful of soldiers cheer for him.

But now when the priest calls Baahubali for doing the same, all the soldiers give a lion roar and keep calling his name.

> Baahubali... Baahubali...

- Why didn't they cheer for Bhallaladeva when the same amount of soldiers were distributed between Bhallaladeva and Baahubali?
- Evil character of Bhallaladeva is revealed to the soldiers and people only after this war. How come they don't like him? How is this not cheering justified? After all he also equal role to play in the war along with Baahubali.
- Does this suggest that his evil character was known to them from the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer give enough details from film prospective but this was more elaborated in animated show [Baahubali: The Lost Legends](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5523460/), which act as a prequel to the films.

**Spoilers Ahead** from the show:

- In S01E01 aka The Beginning, Baahubali was ready to take punishment for breaking *Pradhan Guru*'s instruction just to save villagers from bandits attack. During the same episode public cheer for him when he accepted his punishment happily because for him people's life are more important then his own.

  Bhallaladeva on the other hand went to bring soldiers rather then risking his own life as Baahubali did and he himself cheered for Baahubali but that was pretentious.
- In S01E08 aka Riot In Mahishmati, Baahubali was able to solve a riot between Mahishmati people and Prayag Rajya people and both people united in end and cheered for him.

So Baahubali earned the love of his people by his good heart which came out for cheer for him.

Answer (score 2):

**Why didn't they cheer for Bhallaladeva when the same amount of soldiers were distributed between Bhallaladeva and Baahubali?**

They didn't cheer Ballaladeva and cheered Bahubali not because they already knew Ballaladeva is evil, but because Bahubali was their favorite. They have no special affection towards Ballaladeva. But they are bound with Bahubali and his generous approach to them. There are scenes justifying this in the film (Bahubali having food with Kattappa and other soldiers). If it was because they already knew Ballaladeva was evil, they wouldn't have cheered even after beheading the bull.

Comment: Only people who cheered are less than 10 apart from his loyal soldiers. We know that Bahubali is generous. I forgot to add in the question.

Comment: They didn't know Ballaladeva was evil. The only thing was that they prefer Bahubali over him. There was no dislike for Ballaladeva. They considered him a normal  'Senanayak' and that's why they cheered him after the beheading of the bull. Since their affection and love towards Bahubali was many times more than that to Ballaladeva, and in their mind, Bahubali was their future King, they cheered Bahubali in advance.